# Elastic search cumulative sum aggregation via kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a date histogram which displays the responsiveness of my API and I want to add cumulative graph which shows how many times that API was executed, in order to find a correlation.

This is the relevant link to ELK guide, but not sure how to configure it in kibana.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Pipeline cumulative aggregation on timeseries based data can be visualized using the Visual Builder.

More info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/time-series-visual-builder.html